# Failed to attach: unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed

Tags: android, memory, debuggers, frida, tracing

I'm trying to bypass Frida (Android) local port scanning detection, so I followed [this guide.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139198) The sequence of commands I used are : *(magic_man is alias for frida_server)*

```
adb root
adb push magic_man /data/local/tmp/
adb shell "chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/magic_man"
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/magic_man --listen=unix:/data/local/tmp/magic_socket &"
adb forward tcp:27042 localabstract:/data/local/tmp/magic_socket
```

Now I'm using a Custom ROM (close to AOSP), it isn't rooted but I can enable root access for ADB only.

So, what I noticed after running these commands the checking `ls -l` inside `/data/local/tmp` that `magic_socket` is not created. and if I run simple trace commands like `frida-trace -U -i open YouTube` , it shows me :

> `Failed to attach: unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed`

If I just use the below command, `frida-trace` is working correctly. But then the app is able to detect frida.

```
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/magic_man &"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there any other way to do the same? the docs of frida look incomplete and outdated.